# How to stop vscode from de-indentating my latex project?

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

Kinda new into all of this coding stuff, so will probably sound stupid. I use vscode with the latex workshop extension, but it seems to delete my indentations every time i save my document. It creates a "dummy" file called `__latexindent_temp.tex` and it removes all of my indentations, then deletes itself. Is there any way to stop it from un-indenting my stuff, or even better get it to auto indent whenever i start a new environment (which i thought would be the default instead of deleting indentations lol)?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have the setting to automatically format code is true, and you might want to set it as false.

The setting id is `editor.formatOnSave`. You can search this in VS Code settings and make sure it is unticked. Alternativly, you can add

```
    editor.formatOnSave": false
```

in your `setting.json` file of VS Code

Comment: Is there a way to set this for specific files or languages? I like autoformat on save for whenever i code in other stuff, but the setting seems to be global

Comment: @JerJer you can simply disable the extension that is responsible for formatting your `*.tex` file